# MS Access not getting up-to-date records in multiple users environment

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Access application used by multiple users.

Program and Data split into two files, program is located in user's hard disk, while data file is located in Shared folder in Server.

The big program is that sometime users are not able to get up-to-date records created or modified by another user until the Access restarts.

I am wonder if there is any cache, so Access just get old data. Please advise. Thank you very much.

```
query = "SELECT Max([ID])As MaxID FROM Entry"

Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(query)

If IsNull(rs.Fields("MaxID").Value) Then
    largestId = 0
Else
    largestId = rs.Fields("MaxID").Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Access does cache data. You could try to open the recordset as a snapshot (and use Nz):

```
query = "SELECT Max([ID])As MaxID FROM Entry"
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(query, dbOpenSnapshot)
largestId = Nz(rs.Fields("MaxID").Value, 0)
```

and/or to requery the recordset:

```
query = "SELECT Max([ID])As MaxID FROM Entry"
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(query)
rs.Requery
largestId = Nz(rs.Fields("MaxID").Value, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, may I know what is the function of dbOpenSnapshot or other options. I searched MS document, but still I don't fully understanding what exactly they are and how to choose the options. Thanks again.

Comment: It reads all records in one go. Shouldn't mean much here with one record only, but that Access doesn't know when the recordset is opened, so perhaps it behaves differently than being opened as the defaul dynaset. Just highlight the word in the code an press F1 and the webpage with documentation should open.

Comment: A snapshot is read only as opposed to a dynaset which is editable, I don't think it makes any difference to the records all being loaded at rs opening